# Android butter knife in a activity

Tags: android, android-activity, butterknife

I am just trying to use butter knife in my activity. Added the latest jar and run the application. But Nothing is working. Here is my code. Whats wrong in this

```
@InjectView(R.id.buttonClick) Button buttonClick;
@InjectView(R.id.textField) TextView textField;

@OnClick(R.id.buttonClick) void sayHello(){
    textField.setText("Hello");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
}
```

Comment: Does logcat say something?

Comment: No, Nothing. No errors.

Comment: Did you enabled "Fatory Path"?

Comment: @Palak factory path ? how ?

Comment: Oh yes, Got. I forgot to enable Annotations Processing. Thanks.